# I can't get the summon command to work in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently making a boss fight for some of my friends and I can't get the summon command to work and give then entity the right amount of health, even though I use the correct attribute names and such, the command I'm trying to use is this:

> /summon minecraft:wither_skeleton ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:""well_dweller"",CustomNameVisible:1,Glowing:1,Health:300,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:300},{Name:"generic.followRange",Base:103},{Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Base:0.7f},{Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Base:0.2f},{Name:"generic.attackDamage",Base:4}],HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:iron_sword",tag:{Enchantments:[{id:knockback,lvl:2}]},Count:1},{id:"minecraft:iron_sword",Count:1}],ArmorItems:[{tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4}]},id:"minecraft:golden_boots",Count:1},{tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:2}]},id:"minecraft:iron_leggings",Count:1},{tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:2}]},id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:player_head",tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Wither,display:{Name:'{"text":"Well dwellers head"}'}},Count:1}],ArmorDropChances:[0F,0F,0F,2F],ActiveEffects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:24,Duration:100}]}

However, like I said, it won't work. Please help I have to get this finished by tomorrow.

Comment: I added a generic [java-edition] tag, is it the correct Minecraft version?

Comment: What is the exact Minecraft version?

Comment: Are you using a command block or typing it straight into chat?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there are too many quotes (`""well_dweller""`) in part of the command. In 1.18 you need to do `CustomName:'{"text":"Name Here"}'`. You also need to change `generic.maxHealth` to `minecraft:generic.max_health` (and do a similar thing with the rest of attributes).

This worked for me:

```
/summon minecraft:wither_skeleton ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:'{"text":"well_dweller"}',CustomNameVisible:1,Glowing:1,Health:300,Attributes:[{Name:"minecraft:generic.max_health",Base:300},{Name:"minecraft:generic.follow_range",Base:103},{Name:"minecraft:generic.knockback_resistance",Base:0.7f},{Name:"minecraft:generic.movement_speed",Base:0.2f},{Name:"minecraft:generic.attack_damage",Base:4}],HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:iron_sword",tag:{Enchantments:[{id:knockback,lvl:2}]},Count:1},{id:"minecraft:iron_sword",Count:1}],ArmorItems:[{tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4}]},id:"minecraft:golden_boots",Count:1},{tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:2}]},id:"minecraft:iron_leggings",Count:1},{tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:2}]},id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:player_head",tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Wither,display:{Name:'{"text":"Well dwellers head"}'}},Count:1}],ArmorDropChances:[0F,0F,0F,2F],ActiveEffects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:24,Duration:100}],}
```

Make sure to run this in a command block.

Comment: thanks so much this really helped me